# A committee consists of 12 members. Each pair of members of the committee either mutually like each other, or mutually dislike each other.

Tags: combinatorics

A committee consists of 12 members.  Each pair of members of the committee either mutually like each other, or mutually dislike each other.  Each member likes exactly 6 other members.  Is it necessarily possible to sit all 12 members around a round table so that any two adjacent members like each other?

Comment: Thoughts on this question? Have you tried with smaller numbers like a total of $4$ members with every member liking exactly $2$ others? This will give you an idea of whether or not such a situation is possible.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: Yes, this can be shown to be true using _Hall's marriage theorem_. This is made easier by the fact that all likes are reciprocal and that, because the member is not counted among the 6 members they like, even a group of 6 has to like someone outside the group.

Answer (score 1):

[[image: <span class=]$12$-gon construction">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLwGz.png)

this is an example, every line connect two members mutually like another, and for two members not connected by a line, they mutually dislike others.

This is quite symmetric, but I'm not sure if there are other symmetric or non-symmetric solutions.

Edit: This table is constructed before we actually know who likes which people, if the relation between likes and dislikes are given first, then it should apply more effort to ensure the existence of the permutation.